# Azure free website NodeJS websocket no longer connecting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Android app that uses websockets via a NodeJS server hosted with Azure. For the passed six months, everything has been fine. Today, all is not fine. When I try to connect to my server, I get the response "No address associated with hostname."

I have websockets enabled in my config tab in the management console, also  in the web.config file so that Node handles the websocket and not iis. I have changed nothing, toggled the websocket settings, nothing works. I have restarted the server many times. I also created a new website and migrated everything, still the same issue. I cannot get tech support from Microsoft because the website is a free one. I am aware that there is a max of 5 connections to the websocket; this is not the issue.

My server is using the 'ws' websocket module. I have taken my server.js code down to the minimum for testing. This is it now...

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: process.env.PORT || 8080 });
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {});
ws.on('close', function closing(code, message) {});

if (ws.readyState == 1)
ws.send('message from the server!');
});
```

It still does not work. I replaced the entire file with the code below and the server responds with text in the browser. Of course, this is not websocket, but it shows that the server is able to respond to http requests.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
res.end('Hello, world!');

}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Has anything changed with the usage of websockets? Have recent restrictions been placed I am unaware of?

Comment: <webSocket enabled="false" /> is in web.config, by the way.

Comment: When I view my website in browser with the websocket code, browser outputs "Not implemented".

Comment: Strangely enough, after 2 hours, it just started working again by itself. I did not change anything...

Comment: Back link to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32296b34-a315-4553-8fcd-c4c01173a4d4/have-changes-been-made-to-azure-websites-concerning-websockets?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview